# regenerative braking

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, supercapacitor

I have a 10kW, 72 V golden motor motor and motor controller. When regeneration occurs, the battery terminal voltage increases to more than 72 V. Is there any way to capture this energy to a separate capacitor bank?

Answer (score 1):

IT would be difficult to separate the motor drive circuits from the capacitors; a better approach would be to just charge the caps from the battery when VBATT > 72 V. However, you won't be able to store much energy in the caps -- it's not practical to do this.

Comment: thanks jp314 .how can i charge my cap bank it is a 16v bank.do i need to use a buck converter?

Comment: @frank Yes, that's the right idea.  You have a buck converter that you enable at some delta above 72V, that bucks the voltage down to 16V.  There are lots of other considerations like possibly limiting the current, adding hysteresis and safety. (If the battery voltage rises too high because your cap bank is already charged it can be dangerous.  You might want a resistive element to burn off the excess energy as heat.)

Comment: You are almost building an electric car. By the way, you have to control the regeneration current. Which is another degree of complexity for capacity charging.

Comment: *Even for an electric car*, you still need a resistor grid to dump energy that the battery can't absorb back.  Otherwise there is no way to dissipate the energy gain of going down a long mountain grade.  Brakes certainly won't cut it.  Aerodynamic drag may be useless too, if you're on a low speed road full of switchbacks.

Comment: My point is that it is not really practical to store significant amounts of energy in capacitors compared to what is likely available in a battery.

Answer (score 1):

Usualy isn't done in that way. A typical VFD has a rectifier from mains voltage and then capacitor bank, If the voltage exceeeds a defined threshold then a IGBT transistor switches the braking resistor on (between VDC + and -) and dumps the excess of energy. More costly VFD has a bidirectional rectifier that transfers the energy back to mains.
In your case, similar approch can be done. If you want to recycle the energy you would need a large capacitor bank, larger is, less the voltage rise will be. Or you can hook a parallel resistor and power transitor to dump the energy.
I don't see any issue regarding the momentary high voltage rise on the battery. Any other way would give more complexity without any benefits.